# Ruta relativa de imagenes html

Tags: html, html5, img, src

He creado una página web y he puesto unas cuantas imágenes,no obstante no consigo que se visualicen estoy probando con distintas rutas pero ninguna parece funcionar,ahora mismo tengo algo así:

`<img src="../padlock.png" alt="register" width="128" height="128">`

Explico como están las carpetas;desktop-->lab-->sew(esta carpeta contiene el código html,php,css,etc... y también la carpeta images(que contiene a su vez las imagenes que van en el código html)).
Otra opción ha sido esta,pero tampoco funciona,¿alguna idea?:

`<img src="../../../down-arrow.png" alt="download" width="128" height="128">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si la dirección es esta:

```
Desktop/lab/sew/img/padlock.png
```

y quieres acceder a la imagen desde sew puedes hacer esto: `src="img/padlock.png`"
si estás en una subcarpeta deberás acceder a la carpeta que contenga la carpeta `img`
por ejemplo, dentro de `sew` haces una carpeta llamada `pages`, para acceder a la imagen desde pages puedes hacer esto

```
src="../img/padlock.png"
```

Si siguiese sin funcionar, puedes correr un archivo PHP en tu `localhost`, puedes probas a escribir la URL en la que te encuentras y compararla con la URL en la que tienes la imagen, eso se hace así

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

Pongamos que eso devuelve algo como http://localhost/sew/pages/index.php
Así sabes que estás en una subcarpeta y podrás acceder a las otras carpetas

Da igual el número de veces que pongas ../ no va a ir más hacia atrás

Comment: Seguía sin funcionar al final usé hipervinculos a unsplash y freeicon para solucionarlo.